# How do i query mysql database using where like or like in array?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do i query mysql database using where like (array) or like (array)?

Comment: USE IN CLAUSE QUERY

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN (ietm1,item2,item3)`

Comment: USE IN CLAUSE QUERY BUT IT RETURN ONLY EXACT MATCHES

Comment: Why don't you use [Google](http://google.com). It is a web search engine owned by Google Inc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TRY TO USE **OR**

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field like '%ietm1%' OR field like '%item2%' OR field like '%item3%'
```

**OR**

```
        <?php

    $sql = array('0'); // Stop errors when $words is empty

    $words =array('df','sdfds','dsfdsf');

    foreach($words as $word)
    {
        $sql[] = 'field  LIKE %'.$word.'%';
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE '.implode(" OR ", $sql);

    echo $sql;

    ?>
```

Comment: Please try not to answer questions which can easily get answered doing a simple web search.